# style air application

Tags: google-maps, air, coding-style

for school we are making an air application and we've run into some questions, things we don't know how to do.

Where can we find information on how to style our air application, we would like to get rid off the windows border and make something like kuler.

another problem is how to make google maps run in air?

we would really appreciate some help here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few links, but then I realized you didn't mention which kind of AIR apps ?
as3 or javascript ?

Custom chrome apps are easy in flash, as you can see in [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/articles/custom_chrome_app.html). I have no experience with AIR apps from Dreamweaver, but it should be pretty simple.

As for the google maps, depends what technology you use but there are both versions: [ajax](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html) and [as3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/) versions available.

Comment: it's as3, and the air project is made in flex builder 3 not in dreamweaver.

Comment: Then this should be a good start: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/custom_chrome.html